# How can I get this python package to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, terminal, package

I have to use the following Python Package to scan many .txt files in a directory but I can't get it to work (My programming experience is very limited):

https://pypi.org/project/readability/

With this program I should be able to scan .txt files and get an output about its readability in a csv file. (I am using macOS)

This is the description of how to use it:

```
$ readability --help
Simple readability measures.

Usage: readability [--lang=<x>] [FILE]
or: readability [--lang=<x>] --csv FILES...

By default, input is read from standard input.
Text should be encoded with UTF-8,
one sentence per line, tokens space-separated.

Options:
  -L, --lang=<x>   Set language (available: de, nl, en).
  --csv            Produce a table in comma separated value format on
                   standard output given one or more filenames.
  --tokenizer=<x>  Specify a tokenizer including options that will be given
                   each text on stdin and should return tokenized output on
                   stdout. Not applicable when reading from stdin.
```

If I understand it correctly I only need Terminal to run this program?
I need to scan a whole Folder with .txt files and want to have the output for all of these files in a csv file. According to the instructions this should be possible.

So I tried to use a terminal command like this:

```
$ readability [--lang=<en>] --csv /Users/xxx/Desktop/SEC10K.1
```

But when I press enter I only get this error message in Terminal:

```
-bash: en: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? And how i am supposed to do it correctly? Thanks !

Comment: Try : `$ readability --lang=en --csv /Users/xxx/Desktop/SEC10K.1`

Comment: Hi @mahesh I get an error thats even longer when i try it like this. But I can't post it in the comments because it says that it is too long.

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of the error?

Comment: @mahesh Sorry my mistake I had a typo in the directory! And thank you SO much it (kinda) Works !! Only problem: The results get printed out in Terminal but not in a .csv file - Do you maybe also have a solution for this?

Comment: I will write an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets '[]' denote that the argument is optional and the angle brackets '<>' are used to put place holder examples where it is expected that you fill in with your own stuff. For more info on how to read man-pages, type :

```
$ man man
```

For your case, you need to run `$ readability --lang=en --csv /Users/xxx/Desktop/SEC10K.1`. If you need to put it into a .csv file, then, run:

```
$ readability --lang=en --csv /Users/xxx/Desktop/SEC10K.1 > out.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this works perfectly !! Only problem I have now is that I get the error: Argument list too long - Because the directory contains about 4500 .txt files

Comment: This could be due to some limitations in the module itself. Maybe you can contact the creators and ask them how to handle such cases.